# List all minted tokens in SmartContract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens

I have a `Smart Contract` that I'd like to build a web based marketplace app for. How can I list all available "Items" in the contract. Seeing as there is no upper limit to the number of minted Items, how can I implement pagination and search?

What is a best practice and scalable solution:

- to simply return the `Items[]` array
- sync the array with my database on `Transfer` and other events
- other suggestions?

  ```
  pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

  contract Item is ERC721{

    struct Item{
        string name; // Name of the Item
        uint level; // Item Level
        uint rarityLevel;  // 1 = normal, 2 = rare, 3 = epic, 4 = legendary
    }

    Item[] public items; // First Item has Index 0
    address public owner;

    function Item() public {
        owner = msg.sender; // The Sender is the Owner; Ethereum Address of the Owner
    }

    function createItem(string _name, address _to) public{
        require(owner == msg.sender); // Only the Owner can create Items
        uint id = items.length; // Item ID = Length of the Array Items
        items.push(Item(_name,5,1)) // Item ("Sword",5,1)
        _mint(_to,id); // Assigns the Token to the Ethereum Address that is specified
    }

  }
  ```